# value not showingcorrectly on hover in d3-sankey

Tags: d3.js, sankey-diagram

The nodes on the second and third columns are not showing their correct value. Can someone please help? What am I doing wrong? Here's the html link for my graph.
Thanks a lot,
Rini

https://mehtadatalab.web.illinois.edu/II/haneke_copy/haneke3and.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We want the tooltip to display the number of ingoing (source) links and outgoing (target) links. Since these are all stored in two arrays bound to the data, we can count the length of each array (sourceLinks and targetLinks.)

These arrays are generated for each data after calling [d3.sankey](https://github.com/d3/d3-sankey#sankey).

```js
var rect = node.append("rect")
    .append("title")
    .text(d => d.sourceLinks.length + d.targetLinks.length)
```

Comment: Thanks so much, Hugo. I wanted the middle column to reflect the number of roles for each actor, and so used just .text(d => d.sourceLinks.length). Thanks again!

Comment: No problem. Be sure to accept the answer if it helped you.